# R: why is boxplot(x,log="y") different from boxplot(log(x))?

Tags: r, boxplot

```
delme <- exp(rnorm(1000,1.5,0.3))
boxplot(delme,log="y")
boxplot(log10(delme))
```

Why are the whiskers different in this 2 plots?

Thanks
Agus

Comment: Your plots show the difference between summary(delme) and summary(log10(delme)), with regards to 1st Qu, Median and 3rd Qu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that in your first plot you just changed the y axis to log, so the values you plot still range between 1 and 10. In this plot the `y` axis is a log scale. The whiskers on this axis look different because the space between each "tick" (ie axis break) is not constant (there is more space between 2 and 4 than between 10 and 8)

In the second plot, you take the log of the values then plot them, so they range from .2 to 1, and are plotted with a linear y axis.

Look at the `summary` for both of the normal and `log` transformed dataframes

Comment: Yes, right. In the first case it computes `median(x)` and shows the position of `log10(median(x))` while in the second we have `median(log10(x))`.  I would say that, in general, it would be better having the boxplot(log(x)) but with the y-axis values in the original scale. Sort of `boxplot(log(x), exp="y")` (which does not exist but is easy to make). The point is that the boxplot of the log-transformed value is better except that the original scale is normally easier to interpret.