# Can I use log whiskers on a log-scale boxplot?

Tags: r

When I plot a boxplot with a log scale, the whiskers are based on the un-logged data.

```
x <- rlnorm(n=50, meanlog=0, sdlog=1)
library('beeswarm')
beeswarm(x, log=TRUE)
boxplot(x, add = TRUE, outline = FALSE)
```

[image]

[Of course](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28296634/1944384), if I manually log the data first, then the whiskers reflect this transformation.

```
beeswarm(log(x))
boxplot(log(x), add = TRUE, outline = FALSE)
```

[image]

Is it possible to have the axis from the first graph with the whiskers of the second? That is, can I plot the unlogged data on a log axis, but still have "logged" whiskers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the values calculated by `boxplot(log(x))` and transform them back onto the original scale of `x`. I'm not sure how meaningful the resulting plot is though:

```
x <- rlnorm(n=50, meanlog=0, sdlog=1)
library('beeswarm')
beeswarm(x, log=TRUE)
box = boxplot(log(x), add = FALSE, plot = FALSE, outline = FALSE)
box$stats = exp(box$stats)
box$conf = exp(box$conf)
bxp(box, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice (+1). However, what do you mean by "I'm not sure how meaningful the resulting plot is"?

Comment: By convention, the whiskers represent 1.5 * the interquartile range- when you calculate the whiskers on the log-transformed variable and then show them against the raw values it could be misleading. But you know better than me what the plot is supposed to represent.

Comment: Ah yes, good point. Well, it's biological data, and hence (probably) log-normal. Thus, it should ideally be plotted on a log axis, and IMO it's more biologically relevant to have some meaningful units for labels. FWIW [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/47859/20013) also suggests I should calculate whiskers on log values, but differs because the axes are also labelled with the logged values. So in my case, would "convention" interpret whiskers as being in arithmetic space even if the axis is in log space? [This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/112705/20013) struggles…

Comment: with similar issues, but [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/13429/20013) suggests that computing log whiskers is fine. I guess another point is that whiskers can mean different things out of different programs anyway, so I'll just stick its meaning in the figure legend and methods. Thanks for that though, it was excellent to think more deeply about it!